# Реализация мини калькулятора

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Народ, помогите пожалуйста реализовать мини калькуляцию, есть 1 селект со списком машин и 2 инпута типа number где нужно задать часы и км, при выборе всего что нужно и вводе данных в инпуты  подсчет происходит таким образом: определенная машина из списка определенная цена за час умножается на кол-во часов(из 1-го инпута) + так же определенная машина из списка определенная цена за км умножается на кол-во км(из 2-го инпута), код ниже, но что то он не пашет у меня)

```js
function calculate(carPrice) {
  var cars = {
    'Toyota Camry 40': 2500,
    'Toyota Camry R4': 3300,
    'KIA Optima': 3000
  };

  var oneKm = {
    'Toyota Camry 40': 51,
    'Toyota Camry R4': 41,
    'KIA Optima': 47
  };


  $('#hour').blur(function() {
    var cl = $('#hour').val;
    var Km = $('#distance').val;
    console.log(Km);
    var total = cars[carPrice.value] * cl + Km * oneKm[carPrice.value];
    if (!isNaN(total)) {
      $('#total').text(total);
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="brand" onclick="calculate(this)">
    <option value="Toyota Camry 40">Toyota Camry 40</option>
    <option value="Toyota Camry R4">Toyota Camry R4</option>
    <option value="KIA Optima">KIA Optima</option>
  </select>

  <input type="number" id="hour" min="1" max="500" placeholder="Предположительное время аренды (ч)" step="1" />

  <input type="number" id="distance" min="1" max="500" placeholder="Предположительное расстояние (км)" step="1" />

</form>
<div class="total">Сумма <span id="total"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Сделайте, пожалуйста, ваш код запускаемым и отделить JavaScript от HTML.

Comment: ответ помог?????

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cars = {
  'Toyota Camry 40': 2500,
  'Toyota Camry R4': 3300,
  'KIA Optima': 3000
};

var oneKm = {
  'Toyota Camry 40': 51,
  'Toyota Camry R4': 41,
  'KIA Optima': 47
};
$("#brand").change(foo);
$('#hour').change(foo);
$('#distance').change(foo)

function foo() {
  var cl = $('#hour').val();
  var Km = $('#distance').val();
  var car = $("#brand option:selected").val();
  var total = cars[car] * cl + Km * oneKm[car];
  if (!isNaN(total)) {
    $('#total').text(total);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="brand">
    <option value="Toyota Camry 40">Toyota Camry 40</option>
    <option value="Toyota Camry R4">Toyota Camry R4</option>
    <option value="KIA Optima">KIA Optima</option>
  </select>

  <input type="number" id="hour" min="1" max="500" placeholder="Предположительное время аренды (ч)" step="1" />

  <input type="number" id="distance" min="1" max="500" placeholder="Предположительное расстояние (км)" step="1" />

</form>
<div class="total">Сумма <span id="total"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var cars = {
'Toyota Camry 40': 2500,
'Toyota Camry R4': 3300,
'KIA Optima': 3000
  };

  var oneKm = {
'Toyota Camry 40': 51,
'Toyota Camry R4': 41,
'KIA Optima': 47
  };


$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").on("change", function(){
var cl = $('#hour').val();
var Km = $('#distance').val();
var car = $('#brand').val();
var total = cars[car] * cl + Km * oneKm[car];
if (!isNaN(total)) {
  $('#total').text(total);
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select id="brand">
<option value="Toyota Camry 40">Toyota Camry 40</option>
<option value="Toyota Camry R4">Toyota Camry R4</option>
<option value="KIA Optima">KIA Optima</option>
</select>

<input type="number" id="hour" min="1" max="500" placeholder="Предположительное время аренды (ч)" step="1" />

<input type="number" id="distance" min="1" max="500" placeholder="Предположительное расстояние (км)" step="1" />

</form>
<div class="total">Сумма <span id="total"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое: cars и oneKm ограничены областью видимости функции calculate. Вложенная функция об этих массивах может и не знать. Если вы вызываете вложенную функцию раньше родительской.
Второе: чтобы передать в массив данные их надо сначала вытащить. Например так:  `$("#brand").val();`
Третье: мало объявить функцию, надо ещё её вызвать. Вложенная функция сама по себе не сработает. Её надо вынести или вызывать родительскую функцию событием, а уже внутри делать вызов вложенной.
Ну и мой вариант кода:

```
    var cars = {
    'Toyota Camry 40': 2500,
    'Toyota Camry R4': 3300,
    'KIA Optima': 3000
  };

  var oneKm = {
    'Toyota Camry 40': 51,
    'Toyota Camry R4': 41,
    'KIA Optima': 47
  };

 $('#hour').blur(function() {
    var cl = $('#hour').val();
    var Km = $('#distance').val();
    var carPrice = $("#brand").val();
    var total = cars[carPrice] * cl + Km * oneKm[carPrice];
    if (!isNaN(total)) {
      $('#total').text(total);      
    }
  });
```

Ссылочка на поиграться: http://codepen.io/Ssssory/pen/WRGdyZ

Comment: Ммм... да. И ещё один косяк. сумма пересчитывается только при потере фокуса первого инпута. если менять содержимое второго, то ничего не меняется. Ну, думаю, тут способ решения очевиден.